# No device file for partition in /dev/

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, fdisk

I did partition /dev/sda1 using fdisk.

After creating two partitions, saved the table. And rebooted the server. But there is no device file present for new partitions.

```
:~$ sudo fdisk -l 

Disk /dev/sda: 32.2 GB, 32212254720 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3916 cylinders, total 62914560 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0007fd94

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    60817407    30407680   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        60819454    62912511     1046529    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        60819456    62912511     1046528   82  Linux swap / Solaris

:~$ 

:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda1

Disk /dev/sda1: 31.1 GB, 31137464320 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3785 cylinders, total 60815360 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1bec54ef

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1p1        10485760    60815359    25164800   83  Linux
/dev/sda1p2            2048    10485759     5241856   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

:~$ 
:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: VMware, VMware Virtual S (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 32.2GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  31.1GB  31.1GB  primary   ext4            boot
 2      31.1GB  32.2GB  1072MB  extended
 5      31.1GB  32.2GB  1072MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.4 linux on VMPlayer.

Comment: Thanks for the added info. How did you create the new partitions?

Comment: using fdisk with options n and w